# How to allow any version in Snapshot repo

Tags: continuous-integration, nexus

We're building feature branches into a version 'feature_'. Each feature build will produce the same version. Since these are no releases, I want to deploy the artefacts into the Snapshots repo, but Nexus does not allow versions without 'SNAPSHOT' into the Snapshot repo.

How to configure Nexus to allow any version in a repo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by appending '-SNAPSHOT' to the branch version.
It's quite tricky to get Maven in Jenkins to use the right version. The way I solved it now is like this. In the build job configure Git to build the branches `origin/feature/*`. Then:

- In the 'build' section, first thing to do is execute a shell command to construct a file 'env.properties' containing the feature branch version to be used by the Maven build command.

  `echo BRANCH_VERSION="feature_${GIT_BRANCH##*/}-SNAPSHOT" > env.properties`

  This uses the GIT_BRANCH environment property of Jenkins. The '##*/' is a [Bash Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) which strips everything from the parameter value except the part after the last '/' character.
- Then use the [Environment Injector Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin) to 'inject environment variables' to the build job using the 'env.properties' created in the previous step.
  Put 'env.properties' in the 'Properties File Path' field.
- Use Maven to build a versioned pom with the correct version using 'Invoke top-level Maven targets':
  `help:effective-pom -Dbuild.number=${BRANCH_VERSION} -Doutput=versioned-pom.xml`. This step is necessary because otherwise the pom in the jar artefact does not contain the correct version causing other problems.
- Use another 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' step to do the actual build and deploy using the pom version created in the previous step: `-f versioned-pom.xml clean source:jar deploy`

That's all folks. If anyone knows a simpler solution, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a Maven restriction. You can still use version like feature_x-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT though.

What are you actually trying to achieve though?

Comment: I wanted to deploy a build of a feature branch so dependant projects can also be build and tested. Taking some distance over the weekend and rethink about this I had come to the same conclusion. Yes, it's a Maven thing and the easiest solution is just to append '-SNAPSHOT' to the branch version.